# In xcode, how do I make an animation stop on an Image?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I know the 'nil' clears the imageView at the end of the animation.  But is there a way to end it on one of the images?  When I run it without 'nil' at the end it's a lovely error.

```
imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"],
                                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"],
                                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"],
                                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"image4.png"],
                                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"image5.png"],
                                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"image6.png"],
                                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"image7.png"],
                                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"image8.png"],
                                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"image9.png"],
                                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"image10.png"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"image0.png"],nil];
       imageView.animationDuration = 0.50;
       [imageView setAnimationRepeatCount: 1];
       [imageView startAnimating];
```

Comment: Actually, the `nil` is simply used as a terminator for a variable-length list of arguments to `-arrayWithObjects:`. It's not added to the array, and in fact it's not possible for an instance of NSArray to contain a nil entry. If you omit the `nil` it's a runtime crash because the `-arrayWithObjects:` method has an unterminated list of arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to directly do this, but you could do something like:

```
//set your animationImages as stated in the question
[imageView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[imageView setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
[imageView startAnimating];
[imageView performSelector:@selector(setImage:) withObject:theFinalImage afterDelay:[imageVIew animationDuration]];
```

Basically, you're going to run through the animations once, then replace the animation images with the final static image.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I ended up using a different ImageView for the resulting image, but performselector was a huge boon!  Thanks again!